# When to use dynamic collections in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am working on a translation management platform where users can create new projects, other users can contribute with translations in different languages to these projects and projects don't have any relation to each other. I wonder if it makes sense to create a new collection for each project.

**The question:**

I know this use case is very vague, but can you provide use cases **when to create** and **when not to create** collections dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

here is my 2 cents on this design of the MongoDB collections;

I have collection of shoes, user want to insert a runner. Should i create a new collection?

No.

But shoes and runners have different object structure!

Well you need a footwear collection where each document has a type.

Since this is schema-less database it does not matter if there is difference in the schemes. we should forget about SQL if we are using MongoDB...

But it is so easy to declare a new collection on the client!

And how are you planning to inform the connected clients about the existing collections?

I know! Collection of dynamically created collections!

And how are you going to query that?

Never mind lets create a footwear collection!

Hope this helps!